# Consuming WCF Service Reference: Endpoint not found / 404 page not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

*Hi, I know this topic might look familiar to similar topic but I can tell you that it is after an entire day of searching on related issues that I come for help, because none of the suggested solutions has worked for me.*

I have created a **WCF REST Service Application** with only one service that runs locally on my computer as well as a **ASP.NET WebForm Client** that consumes it (both on individual instance of VS 2013 on a Windows 7).

All the operations of the service work perfeclty fine.

- *GET* operations can be successfully tested in the browser
- *POST* operations can be successfully tested using Postman browser extension.

**Problem**: When I try to access this service using a Service Reference on the client such as:

```
AuthorRESTServiceClient service = new AuthorRESTServiceClient("AuthorServiceBinding");
string value = service.Test(); //GET operation that should return a "Hello World"
```

the client then throws an `EndpointNotFoundException`:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost:49414/AuthorRESTService.svc that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

And contains an inner `WebException`:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Here is the partial code of the **WCF Service Application** server's **Web.config**:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFAuthorEntryService.AuthorRESTService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="WCFAuthorEntryService.IAuthorRESTService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And here's the partial code of the **ASP.NET Webform** client's **Web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="AuthorServiceBinding"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:49414/AuthorRESTService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="AuthorServiceBinding"
                contract="AuthorServiceReference.IAuthorRESTService"
                name="AuthorServiceBinding"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things that stand out to me as possible problems:

1. In the Web.Config for the WCF application you have`<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />` but the URL in the the client uses "http".
2. Is the server always running on port 49414?
3. Are your site's authentication settings correct? Check out [EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357507/endpointnotfoundexception-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at).

Comment: 1. I removed the https binding, the error is still the same.
2. The server is ALWAYS running on port 49414
3. I Use IIS Express integrated in VS 2013. There is no authentication needed in the app.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the service endpoint address, you left it blank. Set the `address` attribute in the `endpoint` element on the services config file to the same value you set in the clients config. Also, depending how you host your WCF service, you might want to set the service base address.

Comment: I tried setting the `address` attribute in the `endpoint` element on the services config file to the same value as the client's config file, (and had therefore to set `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled` to false to allow absolute url) but the result was the same.
I tried adding a host base address to the same value as the client's but nothing changed, I still got both of the exception

Comment: You definitely must specify an service endpoint address. And another thing I see is that you bound the service endpoint to `webHttpBinding` (RESTful) and the client to `basicHttpBinding` (SOAP). Correct that and lets see where it gets us.

Comment: I changed the client to have the same `webHttpBinding` but I got a different exception: _Manual addressing is enabled on this factory, so all messages sent must be pre-addressed_
Do you know where it comes from or how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Web Reference of your REST service on client project,  it will automatically make some changes to your client web.config and just remove protocol mapping section from your WCF web.config file. This may help you.